# comprehension of ancient languages

Tags: greek, hebrew, aramaic

is it necessary to have deep understanding/comprehension of ancient languages to know the "fullness" of the message of the Bible?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a question that belongs here.  While I read Greek, Hebrew, and Aramaic, the most important thing is to know the Bible in its entirety and the context of a passage.  For a complete hermeneutic the Biblical languages are important.  However, if you don't want to do what the Bible says, you won't fully understand it (John 7:17).

Comment: And why would not that q belong here? do you mean on this site? or otherwise?

Comment: I think Perry Webb is technically correct but I think it is such an important question that I will answer it anyway.

Comment: perry, I still do not understand your comment...please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is NO but it depends on how far you want to go.

It is possible and most common to know nothing of the original languages and still understand the central, important teachings of Scripture such as the love of God, Jesus' coming and sacrifice, our becoming His disciples, witnessing to others, the resurrection and many more.  Simply study the scriptures in MORE THAN one version.  I have countless versions of the Bible but I would recommend that you use a minimum of four such as NASB, NRSV, ESV and NIV.  Some would also add NKJV and that is OK too.

As you read these, compare them and meditate on the messages and stories, prayerfully (John 16:13, 14).  But most importantly it is necessary to implement the messages in your life, and the Holy Spirit will reveal more things as you live the life of Christ.

Now, if you want to go deeper, then a study of the original languages can be very rewarding but it is not essential to the study and understanding of the Bible.